# Cascade delete, each one is deleted

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

```
class DistCache
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PlaceInfo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $placeOne;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PlaceInfo")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $placeTwo;
```

This table has two members, both related  to `PlaceInfo` class.
And `PlaceInfo` class doesn't have any member related to `DistCache` class.

Then I want to `delete the DistCache entry when one of two members(placeOne or placeTwo) is deleted`

I googled around and found `cascade="remove" or orphanRemoval=true`, but both looks bit different my purpose.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that for both PlaceInfo object you set `nullable=false` , so when deleting a PlaceInfo, not only have to delete the DistCache entities managed by entityManager, you have to delete the ones in the database too.

I suggest you can use `preRemove` event from [Doctrine life cycle callbacks](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events).
On the remove event of a PlaceInfo record, you query all the DistCache objects which use the deleted PlaceInfo object and remove them first.

In short, you need to :

Add @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks before your class to enable life cycles.

Add preRemove function in PlaceInfo class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $event
 */
public function removeDistCache(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
     $em = $event->getEntityManager();
     // Use $em to query and delete the DistCache entities

}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I can delete DistCache from PlaceInfo entity. I just wonder if it is a good manner to control other entity from the entity. Even getting Repository from entity is prohibited though, but it works well thanks.